# elegant way to replace multiple list of values with a multiple single value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['text'] = ['p', 'S', 'primary','PRI','SECONDARY', 'SEC', 'S', 'TERTIARY','T','third']
```

I would like to replace a list of values like as shown below

a) Replace `P`, `PRIMARY`,`PRI` with `primary`
b) Replace `S`, `SECONDARY`, `SEC` with `secondary`
c) Replace `T`, `TERTIARY`, `THIRD` with `third`

I tried the below

```
df['text'] = df['text'].replace(['P','PRIMARY','PRI'],'primary')
df['text'] = df['text'].replace(['S','SECONDARY','SEC'],'secondary')
df['text'] = df['text'].replace(['T','TERTIARY','THIRD'],'tertiary')
```

But is there any other efficient and elegant way to write this in a single line?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
     text
0   primary
1   secondary
2   primary
3   primary
4   secondary
5   secondary
6   secondary
7   tertiary
8   tertiary
9   tertiary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea for avoid multiple `replace` is use `dictionary` and flatten it to another dict for keys from lists values, for match convert column to uppercase by [`Series.str.upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
d = {'primary': ['P','PRIMARY','PRI'],
     'secondary':['S','SECONDARY','SEC'],
     'tertiary':['T','TERTIARY','THIRD']}


d1 = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
df['text'] = df['text'].str.upper().replace(d1)
print (df)
        text
0    primary
1  secondary
2    primary
3    primary
4  secondary
5  secondary
6  secondary
7   tertiary
8   tertiary
9   tertiary
```

Comment: is that case-insensitive?

Comment: @TheGreat - Unfortuantely not, need convert it to uppercase.